# Py-cord bot goes online but doesnt respond

Tags: python, discord, bots, pycord

I have been trying to make a discord bot but when I put this piece of code tougether the bot turned online but if I use the command there is no response from the bot.

I used the import command from their github

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send(content="Test")
    
bot.run('token')
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get any error at all? Does the bot have the correct permissions and scopes to send the message in the channel?

Comment: @Laif no I am not getting any errors. If I did I would have propably solved this problem

Answer (score 4):

With the latest Pycord versions (starting from 2.0.0b5 if I recall correctly), they use a Discord gateway version high enough that you have to enable the (privileged) [message content intent](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html#discord.Intents.message_content) both on your application's developer site (`https://discord.com/developers/applications/YOUR_APPLICATION_ID/bot`, but you can also go to https://discord.com/developers/applications and then navigate to your bot page from there)
[image: message content intent on the Discord dev page]
and in your code:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
```

With this setup, your bot will receive message events with the content and can actually process your commands

---

Note that once your bot reaches 100 servers, this intent will require you to undergo a whitelisting process by Discord. Until then, you can freely enable the intent to test and build your bot